# Gnome Terminal copy-on-select

Tags: ubuntu-20.04, gnome-terminal

I upgraded Ubuntu to Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS. My current version GNOME 3.36.8, and the windowing system is X11. My Gnome Terminal version is 3.36.2.

Before the upgrade selecting text in the Gnome terminal copied the text to a buffer/clipboard that could be pasted into any desktop application.

After the upgrade, selecting text in the Gnome terminal does not copy the text to the (X11? Gnome? other?) clipboard. I have to press ctrl+shift+c to copy the text.

How do I restore copy-on-select functionality?

Comment: Pasted how exactly? Copy on select uses a different buffer than explicit copy, so the paste method is also different. Are you trying to paste using Ctrl+V?

Comment: Pasted using the same buffer that all the desktop apps share. I think maybe what I'm looking for is a way for copy-on-select and explicit copy to point to the same buffer, or a daemon to keep the buffers synced.

Comment: Could it be that you used to run a clipboard manager app which was configured to keep the two in sync? Most apps support both buffers (select-to-copy corresponds to middle-click-paste), but they're kept completely separate unless you indeed run a daemon to keep them synced.

Comment: I used Mint Linux with Gnome desktop. The two clipboards were kept in sync. I don't remember running a daemon to sync the clipboards. I use the Gnome shell extension "clipboard indicator," but I don't think it syncs the clipboards.

Answer (score 2):

I went down the rabbit hole on this one. I failed to get autocutsel and parcellite to do what I wanted. I thought the problem might be Wayland, but Ubuntu says it is using X11.

I installed [clipit](https://github.com/CristianHenzel/ClipIt), ran it, and opened preferences. I proceeded to check a bunch of boxes without knowing really what they did.
[image]

Now everything that I select anywhere gets copied to the clipboard. And that's just fine. For now. I put clipit in the Startup Applications, and added `-n` so its icon is hidden.
[image]

Problem solved. For now.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, it works fine with gnome terminal on ubuntu 20.04. But it seem to affect sublime text editor copy paste severely. Have you had any similar issue?

Answer (score 1):

Terminator have this option by default
Select what you want it is automatically copy to clipboard and you press the mouse wheel to paste it.

Comment: To improve your answer, Please explain where the option is